# NFS server and delay in using tail -f?

Tags: solaris, nfs, synchronization, tail

We have two Solaris servers, let's call them Alice and Bob.

We also have a Solaris NFS server used by both of them, call it Charlie.

Alice writes to a text logfile on the NFS server, which is then read by Bob, who acts on events in that logfile.

The issue we're having is that there appears to be some delay in Bob seeing updates to the file from Alice.

For testing, I ran on Alice:

```
while [ 0 ]; do echo `date` | tee -a dummy_logfile; sleep 1; done
```

This just writes out the output from `date` every second to a textfile, which is stored on the NFS server.

On Bob, I do:

```
tail -f dummy_logfile
```

I've noticed that there appears to be a delay of ~ 3 seconds for Bob seeing events. The tail -f will echo a logline, then pauses for around 3 seconds, then it spits out 3 seconds worth of log lines, then another 3 seconds of nothing, then outputs another set etc.

However, if on Bob I do:

```
while [ 0 ]; do cat dummy_logfile ; sleep 1; done
```

It repeats each line in dummy_logfile near instantaneously.

So it looks like `tail -f` reading the NFS share is delayed, but cat reading over the NFS share is not. I was under the impression that `tail -f` was near-instant.

Is there anything in the interaction of NFS, buffers, cache, etc. that might explain this behaviour? Does each cat somehow force an update or something?

Also, doing a `tail -f` on Alice (the server generating the dummy_logfile) seems to be near-instant, so it doesn't appear to be some issue with `tail -f` itself.

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe tail -f looks at the attributes of a file to determine the EOF point, but attributes are normally cached for a certain amount of time in NFS. cat simply streams all the bytes.

Mount NFS with the option "noac". This will disable all attribute caching. By default, attributes are cached for a minimum of 3 seconds, which is coincidentally exactly how long your delay seems to be. You can modify the option "acregmin=x" to set that lower, but it seems you'd want the caching disabled entirely.

Caution: this will probably incur a performance hit if you're using the NFS share for anything else.

More NFS info at the man page here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs